# Rails Capistrano deploy_to path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, vpn

I'm trying to deploy my rails app, until now hostet at Heroku, now at DigitalOcean using Capistrano. I've created a "1-Click-Rails-Application", which creates a blank rails app, so when I open the remote server in my webbrowser, the typical rails welcome screen (index.html) shows up. When I ssh to the remote directory, the path to the rails app is:

```
/home/rails/
```

inside of the rails directory are the typical rails folders like controllers etc. So I thought that the correct deploy_to path should be:

```
set :deploy_to, "/home/rails/"
```

I've seen so many different directory suggestions that I really can't figure out what could be right. I had

```
set :deploy_to, "var/www/#{application}"
```

as well, which didn't seem to work either.

I'm glad I've managed to upload my local app to the new vpn server without any errors at all. I want to avoid using a git repo to save the extra costs for a private git repo and push it directly from my computer. The problem is, after a

```
cap production deploy:cold
```

which does a lot and runs through without any errors, doesn't seem to upload anything. At least I can't find any of "my" files on the server. Well, I'm really happy that I got this far but don't understand why my config isn't working. I hope someone can help. Here is my deploy.rb from the config directory. (I'm using rvm.)

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "rvm/capistrano"

set :application, "myApp"
set :user, "root"
set :port, 22
set :deploy_to, "home/rails/"
set :repository, "."
set :scm, :none 
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :checkout, :export
set :use_sudo, false
#set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-2.0.0p195@#{application}"
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_type, :system
server "xx.xxx.xx.xx", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 2.0.0. Thanks a lot!

**Update:**
I was originally following a railscast capistrano deployment tutorial to get my head around this. Thus I created the deploy folder inside the config folder with a production.rb and a staging.rb inside.

Long story short, I've found "my" rails app, inside a var/www/xx.xxx.xx.xx/current/ directory on the server. The path is specified inside the production.rb which looks like this:

```
server "xx.xxx.xx.xx", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/xx.xxx.xx.xx"
```

I could now change the path above to /home/rails but the actual rails app was inside the additional folder named current. How do I have to write the path so that there is no current directory? at least not there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set :deploy_to, "home/rails/"
```

The correct way is:

```
set :deploy_to, "/home/rails/"
```

and for `var` path:

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"
```

Comment: Also while running this command 'cap production deploy:cold' , check the process for any errors.

Comment: What does **for 'var' path** mean / where do I write this? 'cap production deploy:cold' worked without any errors.

Comment: set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}" in deploy.rb

Comment: But doesn't that 'override' the previous :deploy_to path? Edit: Oh I'm sorry I think I misunderstood your answer. Which one of the two do I have to use?

Comment: can u come to skype??

Comment: Thank you very much for the offer, I'm sorry I'm on a very slow internet connection at the moment.

Comment: erharish43.malik@gmail.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35383/discussion-between-harish-malik-and-linusan)

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with the latest version of Capistrano: 3.2.1 and 3.1.0
Perhaps this was fixed in a patch?

Here are the relevant parts of my files:

Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
end
```

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

config/deploy.rb

```
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/wrong_stage_folder'
# make sure this value is ignored.
```

config/deploy/staging.rb

```
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/appname_stage'
```

config/deploy/production.rb

```
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/appname_prod'
```

Run check: cap staging deploy:check --trace

```
INFO [2618043b] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/appname_stage/shared /var/www/appname_stage/releases on example.server.com
```

Works as expected, same for production.